# Not able to rollback DB changes in Aspect in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I have written one aspect around a service class. In the aspect, I am doing some operation in the before section, which I would like to be rolled back if some exception occurs in the enclosed service method.

The service class is as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional
class ServiceA {
   ...
   public void doSomething() {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

The aspect is as follows:

```
  @Aspect
  @Order(2)
  public class TcStateManagementAspect {
  
  ...

  @Around(value = "applicationServicePointcut()", argNames = "joinPoint")
  public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
      throws Throwable {
    ...
    */Before section */

    do some processing and persist in DB
    ...
    Object object = joinPoint.proceed();
    ...
    do some post-processing
  }
}
```

I am seeing an exception in the service method is not rolling back the DB operation in the `Begin Section`. I tried putting `@Transactional` on `@Around`, but it did not help.

In this context, I have gone through the following posts:

1. [Spring @Transactional in an Aspect (AOP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711615/spring-transactional-in-an-aspect-aop)
2. [Custom Spring AOP Around + @Transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057910/custom-spring-aop-around-transactional)

But I am not able to get any concrete idea regarding how to achieve this. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: The transaction starts when the annotated method is entered (i.e. when calling `proceed()`) , not **before**. I am not a Spring user, but did you try to also make the aspect advice method transactional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, what your around advice does must be declared transactional too. You cannot do that directly, because `@Transactional` internally uses Spring AOP via dynamic proxies. However, Spring AOP aspects cannot be the target of other aspects. But you can simply create a new helper `@Component` which you delegate your advice's action to.

Let us assume that the goal is to log the arguments of the `@Transactional` method targeted by your aspect. Then simply do this:

```java
package com.example.managingtransactions;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class TxLogAspect {
  private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TxLogAspect.class);

  @Autowired
  TxLogService txLogService;

  @Pointcut(
    "@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional) && " +
    "!within(com.example.managingtransactions.TxLogService)"
  )
  public void applicationServicePointcut() {}

  @Around("applicationServicePointcut()")
  public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    logger.info(joinPoint.toString());
    // Delegate to helper component in order to be able to use @Transactional
    return txLogService.logToDB(joinPoint);
  }
}
```

```java
package com.example.managingtransactions;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Helper component to delegate aspect advice execution to in order to make the
 * advice transactional.
 * <p>
 * Aspect methods themselves cannot be @Transactional, because Spring AOP aspects
 * cannot be targeted by other aspects. Delegation is a simple and elegant
 * workaround.
 */
@Component
public class TxLogService {
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Transactional
  public Object logToDB(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    jdbcTemplate.update(
      "insert into TX_LOG(MESSAGE) values (?)",
      Arrays.deepToString(joinPoint.getArgs())
    );
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }

  public List<String> findAllTxLogs() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
      "select MESSAGE from TX_LOG",
      (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getString("MESSAGE")
    );
  }
}
```

See? We are passing through the joinpoint instance to the helper component's own `@Transactional` method, which means that the transaction is started when entering that method and committed or rolled back depending on the result of `joinPoint.proceed()`. I.e. what the aspect helper writes to the DB itself will also be rolled back if something goes wrong in the aspect's target method.

BTW, because I never used Spring transactions before, I simply took the example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/ and added the two classes above. Before, I also added this to `schema.sql`:

```sql
create table TX_LOG(ID serial, MESSAGE varchar(255) NOT NULL);
```

Next, I added made sure that `TxLogService` is injected into `AppRunner`:

```java
  private final BookingService bookingService;
  private final TxLogService txLogService;

  public AppRunner(BookingService bookingService, TxLogService txLogger) {
    this.bookingService = bookingService;
    this.txLogService = txLogger;
  }
```

If then at the end of `AppRunner.run(String...)` you add these two statements

```java
    logger.info("BOOKINGS: " + bookingService.findAllBookings().toString());
    logger.info("TX_LOGS: " + txLogService.findAllTxLogs().toString());
```

you should see something like this at the end of the console log:

```
c.e.managingtransactions.AppRunner       : BOOKINGS: [Alice, Bob, Carol]
c.e.managingtransactions.AppRunner       : TX_LOGS: [[[Alice, Bob, Carol]]]
```

I.e. you see that only for the successful booking transaction a log message something was written to the DB, not for the two failed ones.