# @Transactional annotation on the proceed method inside @Around

Tags: transactions, aop, spring-aop

I'm trying to use @Around advice, and the pjp.proceed method needs to be annotated with @Transactional.
Right now it's not working, and as I saw in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711615/spring-transactional-in-an-aspect-aop) , that the nethod annotated with @TransactionalI needs to be inside other class.
In my case, the proceed method (which is the method annotated by the annotation and occurs inside the @Around) is the method I need to be annotated with the @Transactional.
Is it the problem why the @Transactional annotation isn't working for me? It seems as not exactly the same case.

```
@Around("someFunction()")
public Object aroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Annotation annotation) throws Throwable
{
// code before using annotations parameters

    Object proceed = null;
    try { // @Transactional annotation needed for this method, which is on other class
        proceed = pjp.proceed();
}

// code after

    catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

        return proceed;
    }
}
```

I can't think of a way to make it work while still use the @Around advice.
any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Is your requirement to start a transaction for `someFunction()` programmatically ? Also , please share why you are not annotating `someFunction()` with `@Transactional` ?

Comment: By `someFunction()` , I meant the target method .

Comment: @R.G someFunction() is just a function with a pointcut. annotating it can work for me? the transaction is needed only for the function of the proceed().thank you! I'm really new to AOP and spring

Comment: 1. annotating `someFunction()` with `@Transactional` will not work . I meant , the method which the pointcut targets 2. You cannot annotate `proceed()` . The best approach is to annotate `@Transactional` for the method pointcut targets . You can also start a transaction programmatically , encapsulating the `proceed()`. I can share a sample code if you need the programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is completely incomprehensible to me, because the explanation is unclear and ambigous. Please let code speak and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your situation. Like this, the question is only likely to attract lenghty discussions in comments and close votes. Improve your question, then you probably are going to get a precise and helpful answer. Hiding the code you are talking about is not such a good idea.